# How to [en|de]crypt XML using Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, encryption, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xml-encryption

I want to encrypt/decrypt some XML using Xamarin.iOS.

In .NET this is done using the `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` namespaces (and types) found in the `System.Security.dll` assembly.

However the `System.Security.dll` assembly is not part of the profile that is shipped by Xamarin.iOS.

What alternative do I have ?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "some crypt values not available" - it's also unclear what you've tried, what happened, what your requirements are, etc.

Comment: example using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
this can't be avialble at monotouch, i just want simply crypt or change characters un understanble and decrypt, thats all i need but cant find sadly.. in console i can crypt but in monotouch, it just can't

Comment: 1) Do you need to use one of the xml encryption standards, or do you just need to encrypt some data that happens to be xml? 2) You might be able to add the assemblies you need. I'd expect this file to be missing from the default distribution. 3) If this doesn't work out, you can always take a look at BouncyCastle.

Comment: i handle with RijndaelManaged and CryptoStream thanks, i just need  a way to possible between story pages splitview use?

Answer (score 0):

With very few modifications you should be able to build your own `System.Security.dll` using Mono's sources. The trick is to ensure it refers to the BCL shipped with Xamarin.iOS.

That will give you both **xmlenc** (encryption) and **xmldsig** (digital signature) features using the same API (more code sharing) as the desktop (Mono or MS) .NET runtime.

While it's not an *immediate* solution you should take time to file suggestions on [uservoice](http://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-product-suggestions).